# RxJS: How to compose a tree of Reactive Observers?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to use Reactive Programming to create a reusable set of components to assemble processing trees, like a decision tree.

Each node in the tree could have children nodes. The current node can pass the current stream value to the child nodes, in sequence, and perform some operations on the result, decide if it should continue with the next child, or just return upstream.

```
       parent
         |
    +----+-----+
    O1   O2    O3
    |
 +--+--+
C1  C2 C3
```

Say I have a Observable of events. I want to apply a set of Observer sequences to the events, and concantenate the results:

```
event stream:    --e1---------e2--------e3------------------------->
observer stream: --O1---O2---O3----|-->
                        vvvvvvvvvvvv ????? vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                 --O1(e1)--O2(e1)--O3(e1)--O1(e2)--O2(e2)--O3(e3)-->
```

Is that possible? This should be composable, so for example, O1 could be composed of child observers `[C1, C2, C3]`, which would emit a stream like:

```
                 --C1(O1(e1))--C2(O1(e1))--C3(O1(e1))--O2(e1)-->
```

O1 needs to be able to block its children from emitting values. For example, if C1 returns a failure code, we should not execute C2. O1 would then emit a value, and `parent` would decide if it should 'emit' the result from O1, or proceed to O2.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrErPN?editors=001) that demonstrates what I'm going for, you'll need to open the console to see the errors.

My plan was to use method like takeUntil() and takeLast() to do the 'continue or return' logic, like this:

```
// apply event to children until one of them returns 'SUCCESS'
nodeStream(childStreams) {
    return eventStream // Where does this come from?
        .concatMap(childStreams)
        .takeWhile(event => event.result !== 'SUCCESS')
        .takeLast();
}
```

I've gotten as far as something like this, but I can't wrap my head around how to connection the observers (O1, etc):

```
function node(eventSource) {
    let childOne = new Rx.Subject().map(e => e + '1');
    let childTwo = new Rx.Subject().map(e => e + '2');

    let children = Rx.Observable.from([childOne, childTwo]);

    let resultSource =
        // Here be dragons
        // How to concatenate the child observers?
        eventSource.concatMap(function(e) {
            return children;
        });

    return resultSource;
}

// Expected Output:
// onNext: event1
// onNext: event2
// onComplete
function testEvent() {
    // This will be hot in the real world
    let eventSource = Rx.Observable.of('event');

    let resultSource = node(eventSource);

    resultSource.subscribe(
        function(x) {
            console.log('onNext:', x);
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log('onError:', e);
        },
        function() {
            console.log('onComplete');
        }
    );
}
```

I'm stuck on how to apply the children. I'd like to be able to construct a hierarchy of multiple nodeStreams (see the ascii diagram above), so obviously the example above does not work, since both the source and child streams cannot exist at construction time for each node:

```
let c1 = nodeStream();
let c2 = nodeStream();
let c3 = nodeStream();
let o1 = nodeStream([c1, c2, c3]);
let o2 = nodeStream();
let o3 = nodeStream();
let parent = nodeStream([o1, o2, o3]);

eventSource.subscribe(parent);
```

I'm using RxJS, but I assume the solution would be similar with all Reactive libraries.

### Update

For anyone curious, I've solve this problem for now by having each node in my tree return a Promise. The promise model is much easier to reason about for this type of structure. Then, I've wrapped the entire tree with a `Rx.Observable.fromPromise()`

Comment: Could you give an example of an observer you want to apply?

Comment: @Nupf - I added more detail

Comment: I still don't fully understand. Regarding the last point: If the problem is the children not existing before the parent: pass in an empty childstreams array for the creation of the parent and fill that childstreams array later on. As Rx only executes the concatMap on subscription, it will see the most recent version of the childstreams array

Comment: @Nupf - I added some much more more flushed out code that should explain a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

About what you are specifically asking (which is not completely clear to me so forgive me if I misunderstood something), your observers are functions right?

The following should give you something close to what you want.

```
var observerArray = [f1, f2, f3];
return this.eventSource
           .concatMap(function(Ex){
                      return observerArray.map(function (fx){return fx(Ex);});
                    })
```

Your output should be `f1(E1), f2(E1), f3(E1), f1(E2), f2(E2), f3(E2)...`

**UPDATE** :
just saw you added details to your question. The answer remains the same. What happens is instead of an array you will have a tree data structure. As long as that tree data structure has a map function which traverses the tree and collect all nodes in an array, you can use the same code.

```
var observerTree = //some object or library that implements a tree structure;
return this.eventSource
           .concatMap(function(Ex){
                      return observerTree.map(function (fx){return fx(Ex);});
                    })
```

Now how to write the map is dependent on how your tree data structure is but it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems you probably already know about:

Your children actually have to be split into two parts: the subject & the resulting sequence. You need to call onNext on the subject directly.

```
var childOneSubject = new Rx.Subject();
var childOneSequence = childOneSubject.map(e => e + '1');
```

Apart from that your children are hot, which means concatenating them won't lead to the expected results (child1 and child2 fire at the same time - as you only subscribe to child2 after child1 completed you're left with only receiving the onComplete of child2, the onNext has already fired before subscription)

Could you turn it around and make the resultSource a subject and let childOne and childTwo fire onNexts on it? [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nigeqowaki/edit?js,console)

```
function node(eventSource) {  
  var resultSource = new Rx.Subject();
  eventSource.subscribe(e => resultSource.onNext(e + '1')); // child1 
  eventSource.subscribe(e => resultSource.onNext(e + '2')); // child2
  return resultSource;
}

// Expected Output:
// onNext: event1
// onNext: event2
// onCompvare
function testEvent() {
  // This will be hot in the real world
  var eventSource = Rx.Observable.of('event').publish();
  var resultSource = node(eventSource);
  resultSource.subscribe(
    function(x) {
      console.log('onNext:', x);
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log('onError:', e);
    },
    function() {
      console.log('onCompvare');
    }
  );
  eventSource.connect();

}
testEvent();
```

Right now I'm publishing the eventSource to avoid missing the one event it emits. From your last code snippet I assume you can prepare everything beforehand.

Maybe this does not take into account the other points you made - I'll have a look tomorrow, it's late.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so this won't work as you need to execute the children in sequence to possibly stop later children from running.

More questions from the codepen (which sadly errors for me): 
Why are you using subjects at all? Can't you just map over the input observable? I.e.

```
// child
run(eventSource) {
  return eventSource.map(t => {
    t.state.v = t.state.v + this.suffix;
    t.result = this.status;

    return t;
  });
}
```

I simplified a lot here, but maybe this could work [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/suqedutuva/edit?js,console):

```
var eventSource = Rx.Observable.of('event', 'event', 'event');
//children abstracted as just their suffix & status
var childSource = Rx.Observable.of(
  {suffix: 1, status: 1},
  {suffix: 2, status: 0},
  {suffix: 3, status: 1}  
); 

function runChildren(eventSource) {
  return childSource.concatMap(child => {
    if(child.status == 1) return eventSource.map(event => event + child.suffix);
    else return Rx.Observable.throw(child.suffix);
  })
  .catch(error => Rx.Observable.empty());
}


var node = eventSource.concatMap(event => {
  var childEventSource = Rx.Observable.of(event);
  return runChildren(childEventSource);
});

node.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'd appreciate a second look tomorrow - I'll try and apply your comments now

Comment: The problem here is that the code needs to be composable... The children need to be able to have children also. In your simplified examples, the children are just being checked for status, instead of being incorporated in the eventsource stream. I gave the children subjects to show that they should have the same interface as the parent node. I'm starting to think the structure I need would be better suited to promises than reactive programming. I could wrap the whole promise structure in a reactive call.

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it @nupf

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky with proxy stream:

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.merge(
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("first"), "click").map(() => ({"firstSourceData": "first source any data"})),
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById("second"), "click").map(() => ({"secondSourceData": "second source any data"}))
);

var sourceProxy = new Rx.Subject();

var firstStream = sourceProxy.map(() => {
    return {"firstStreamData": "first child any data"}
}).publish();
firstStream.connect();

var secondStream = sourceProxy.map(() => {
    return {"secondStreamData": "second child any data"}
}).publish();
secondStream.connect();

source.flatMap(function(event) {
  var first = firstStream.take(1).publishLast();
  var second = secondStream.take(1).publishLast();

  return Rx.Observable.defer(function() {
    first.connect();
    second.connect();
    sourceProxy.onNext(event);
    return Rx.Observable.empty();
  })
  .merge(first)
  .merge(second)
  //After that place you can composite or aggregate all three values as you want
  .reduce((result, data) => {
    return Object.assign(result, data, event);
  })
})
  .subscribe(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bigbadalien/snd68y0w/)